# 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, outlook, download, attachment

I am trying to download the attachment from a subject specified e-mail.

```
If Msg.Subject = "CALENDAR-EVENT" Then

        'Download the attachment

        Dim itmAttach As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
        Dim saveFolder As String
            saveFolder = "C:\events\"
        Dim dateFormat As String
            dateFormat = Format(itmAttach.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
        For Each objAtt In itmAttach.Attachments
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Next
End if
```

I get the error:

> 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Maybe there is some error with the line:

```
Dim itmAttach As Outlook.MailItem
```

It also would be nice to get the downloaded file's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use the outlook APIs before, neither did I touch VBA for years, but by the looks of it you meant this:

```
If Msg.Subject = "CALENDAR-EVENT" Then
        Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
        Dim saveFolder As String
            saveFolder = "C:\events"
        Dim dateFormat As String
            dateFormat = Format(Msg.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
        For Each objAtt In Msg.Attachments
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Next
End if
```

Error 91 seems to be VBA's NullReferenceException.

Comment: this is working like dream. one more question: 

i wish to save the filename into a variable as the following:

`Dim fileName As String
                fileName = dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName`

after this, i need to use the filename later in the code: 

`csvFilePath = "c:\events\fileName.csv"`

but this is not working. any idea how to do that?

Comment: I think the absolute path should be `fileName = saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName`.